# Laravel 5.5.20: Command not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I am trying to create command:

`php artisan make:command ExampleCommand --command=example`

When I'm trying to launch it - I am getting:

```

[Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]
  Command "example" is not defined.

```

Any ideas?

Comment: Lots could be going on. Did you register the command in app/Console/Kernel.php?

Comment: Why you need `--command` option?

Answer (score 0):

I installed `Laravel 5.5.20` and I run `php artisan make:command ExampleCommand --command=example` code. There was no problem.
I think some of the packages are not installed correctly.

I suggest removing the `composer.lock` file and remove the `vendor` directory and run the `composer install` again.